# Divide the array and create new array

Tags: php

I have array like this

```
array (size=6)
  0 => string '2      16     10     4      0      0      0      0      0'     
  1 => string '0      0      0      4' 
  2 => string '2      15     8      6      0      0      0      0      0' 
  3 => string '0      0      0      3' 
  4 => string '3      18     12     5      0      0      0      0      0' 
  5 => string '0      0      0      2'
```

I want to divide the array and create a new array like

```
array1 (size = 1)
0 => '2 16 10 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4'

array2 (size = 1)
0 => '2 15 8 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3'

array3 (size = 2)
0 => '3 18 12 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2'
```

`array_chunk()` works fine. But it not supported my array

Comment: StackOverflow is not a coding service. Please provide code snippets of what you've attempted so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***You can do it through [array_chunk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php) and `foreach()`***

```
$new_array = array_chunk($original_array,2);

$final_array = [];

foreach($new_array as $arr){
 $final_array[] = $arr[0].' '.$arr[1];
}

print_r($final_array);
```

Output:- https://eval.in/928261

***Note:- If you want to remove extra white-spaces in-between the strings, then use [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)***

```
$new_array = array_chunk($original_array,2);

$final_array = [];

foreach($new_array as $arr){
 $final_array[] = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $arr[0]).' '.preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $arr[1]);
}

print_r($final_array);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/928265

Comment: @Athi  no that's not the correct behaviour. editing question again and again and asking for code is not correct. You have to ask new question regarding that. Thanks

Comment: Sorry sir, Please help me

Comment: @Athi  as i said close this question  by reverting question back to previous and mark answer as accepted,and  then ask a new question input+code-effort_expected outcome. You will get answer for-sure. You can address me the link and if i wll free i will answer also.

Answer (score 1):

use `array_chunk($array_name, 2)`

the above will return a multi dimension array.

Answer (score 0):

Method #1: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/eWIR0))

```
$prepped_copy=preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',$array);  // reduce spacing throughout entire array
while($prepped_copy){  // iterate while there are any elements in the array
    $result[]=implode(' ',array_splice($prepped_copy,0,2));  // concat 2 elements at a time
}

var_export($result);
```

Method #2 ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/GEPbJ))

```
$pairs=array_chunk(preg_replace('/\s+/',' ',$array),2);  // reduce spacing and pair elements
foreach($pairs as $pair){
    $result[]="{$pair[0]} {$pair[1]}";  // concat 2 elements at a time
}

var_export($result);
```

Both Output:

```
array (
  0 => '2 16 10 4 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4',
  1 => '2 15 8 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3',
  2 => '3 18 12 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2',
)
```

To my surprise, Method #1 was actually slightly faster using the small sample dataset (but not noticeably so).